# How to fix Connection Refused error in Kubernetes Steps and Node Executor?

Tags: kubernetes, rundeck

I am trying Rundeck Community edition, more precisely I try to use the Kubernetes steps and node executor.

Everything is going well when setting up the node, I can see the pods in my cluster, but when I try to launch a command, it all fail with a connection error: `(Connection refused)`

Does this ring a bell to someone? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Hello! Do you fill in the Authentication parameters? (model source) https://imgur.com/PkAgJge (this link helps a lot: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cloud-paks/cp-management/2.0.0?topic=kubectl-using-service-account-tokens-connect-api-server)

Comment: What do you mean by "launch a command"? Could you give an example of a command you tried to "launch"? I'm not sure what this means because, according to your post, you can see the pods, meaning you can reach the API.